# how to fetch local express server which is in same directory of frontend project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, deployment, backend

this is my project structure -

backend >

- node_modules >
- .env
- package-lock.json
- package.json
- server.js

frontend >

- index.html
- style.css
- script.js

server.js

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

import express from 'express';
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.send('connected to backend server');
});

// writing a route for jokes
app.get('/api/jokes', (req, res)=>{  // this is right standardised way of writing a route
    const jokes = [
        {
            id: 1,
            joke: "I am a joke 1"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            joke: "I am a joke 2"
        }
    ];

    res.send(jokes);
});

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`served at http://localhost:${port}`);
})
```

sript.js -

```
const url = fetch('/api/jokes');

url.then((response)=>{
    return response.json();
}).then((data)=>{
    console.log(data);
});
```

how can i access the local Api? here I want to access the jokes but this code is not working.

if i run this server on specific port and then directly give this URL to fetch and add this code in my server.js file then it works. but that means I using two different domains for frontend and backend seperately.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:5500');
    next();
});
```

but I don't think its right way to do that, if I did this then what about deployment? does i have to buy two domains ?

how can I make the proper connection between server and frontend without any 2nd or 3rd domain ?

I want to know how can I make the proper connection between the server and frontend without need of any 2nd domain.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to run your API and front-end on different ports. If your preference is to use `then/catch` blocks then just run the fetch like so and if there are any errors it will log them to the console:

```js
fetch('/api/jokes')
   .then(response => {
      return response.json();
   })
   .then(jokes => {
      console.log(jokes);
   })
   .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
   });
```

Also, if you are intentially sending JSON back from the API then common convetion is to use:

```js
res.status(200).json(jokes);
```

Then you can access the first joke like so:

```js
//...

   .then(jokes => {
      console.log(jokes[0]);
   // { id: 1, joke: "I am a joke 1" }
   })

//...
```

Comment: for accessing the local api we have start the server on different port and then i need to fetch this server with full url like fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/jokes");

i need to follow this if i dirctoly try like this fetch("/api/jokes") then this not work.

Comment: @vishwasbabar are your front-end and backend files in the same root directory i.e the same folder? I understand if you are using React for frontend then serve them from different ports but you have a simple html file. You can put these static html, css, js files in a public folder and use express.static to serve them from the public folder.